# using dos commands how can I match a substring from a variable?

Tags: batch-file

using dos commands how can I match substring from a variable.
e.g:  var="Lost = 0 (0% loss)"
I want to check whether var contains "Lost" in it.
I have already tried Contains, like but throwing error.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  

What have you tried so far?  Can you give an example of your input and your desired output?

See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist for some good advice about how to get useful answers to your questions.

Comment: which version of DOS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo %varname%|findstr "string" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo %varname% does not contain "string"
  ) else (echo %varname% contains "string")
```

Note that this can all be on one line if you prefer. If broken across lines, the sequence `) else (` must be on same line, as must the `if` and very first `(`